# Can I create resources and methods in AWS API Gatway using CDK or CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cdk

Currently, I'm learning AWS CDK and I want to create an Api gateway with multiple resources and each with its own methods.

Can I do so using CDK or CLI or do I have to do so from the AWS web console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible from both, here is an example Lambda function with Rest API in CDK:

```
    const transactionFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'TransactionFunction', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      memorySize: 1024,
      timeout: Duration.seconds(10),
      handler: 'index.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../src/lambda/transaction/')),
      environment: {
        REGION: Stack.of(this).region
      }
    });

    const api = new RestApi(this, 'TransactionAPI', {
      description: 'Transactions API',
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'dev'
      },
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        allowHeaders: [
          'Content-Type',
          'X-Amz-Date',
          'Authorization',
          'X-Api-Key',
        ],
        allowMethods: ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
        allowCredentials: true,
        allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS
      }
    })

    const transactions = api.root.addResource('transactions');

    transactions.addMethod('POST', new LambdaIntegration(transactionFunction));

    new CfnOutput(this, 'apiUrl', { value: api.url });
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway-readme.html#defining-apis